# Solution to the matrix equation AX=XB in the form of generalized inverses

Tags: matrix-equations

It is known that the solution (suppose it exists) of Sylvester matrix equation $AX-YB=C$ can be given in the form of generalized inverses as
$$X=A^{-}C + A^{-}ZB + (I-A^{-}A)W,$$
and
$$Y = - (I-AA^{-})CB^{-} +Z - (I-AA^{-})ZBB^{-}$$
with $W$ and $Z$ being arbitrary.
See J. K. Baksalary and R. Kala [Linear Algebra Appl. 25, 41-43 (1979; Zbl 0403.15010)].
My question is how about the matrix equation $AX=XB$?
Can the solution the matrix equation $AX=XB$ be given in the form of generalized inverses as above?

P.S. Note the when $C=0$ the solution the matrix equation $AX=YB$ has the form
$$X=A^{-}ZB + (I-A^{-}A)W,$$
and
$$Y=Z-(I-AA^{-})ZBB^{-}.$$
But if we demand
$$X=A^{-}ZB + (I-A^{-}A)W=Z-(I-AA^{-})ZBB^{-}=Y,$$
we have to solve a more complicated equation which is not needed.
Thus it seems that the solution of matrix equation $AX=XB$ can not be seen as a special case of matrix equation $AX-YB=C$ in the form of generalized inverses.

Comment: isn't $X=0$ a solution?

Comment: Yes, X=0 certainly is a solution. But I want to give a formula for all the other ones.

Comment: In fact, I can find nonzero solution like this $X= (I-A^{-}A)Z (I-BB^{-})$ with Z being arbitrary. But this is not a general formula for all solutions.